# Execute an .exe in Python in Ubuntu/WSL

Tags: python, ubuntu, exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I execute an `.exe` file with Python3 on Ubuntu in WSL? From my searches I found `os.system`, but despite being placed in the correct folder, I cannot find the `.exe` file. I also tried with `os.open` with no results.

```
import os


current = os.chdir('../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/')
os.system("ZAP.exe")
```

Comment: Do you want to open the file, or execute it?

Comment: I have to start an executable. I am on windows but I am using the Ubuntu app

Comment: I'd guess that your path is incorrect, try using an absolute path, e.g. `os.chdir("/mnt/c/Users/.........)`. You can use the other `os` functions to [test for file existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82852/2280890). Opening the windows executable on WSL should be fine, is there a reason you're running this from WSL instead of just from windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expound on [@MichaelMatsaev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73306581/11810933) a bit, what you are attempting to do with the Python example in your question is essentially the same as this Bash construct:

```
cd ../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/
ZAP.exe
```

You'll get a `command not found` from Bash.  Pretty much every Linux app will work the same way, since they all ultimately use some form of syscall in the `exec` family.

When executing *any* binary in Linux (not just Windows `.exe`'s in WSL), the binary must be either:

- On the search `$PATH`
- Specified with a fully-qualified (relative or absolute) path to the binary.

So in addition to @MichaelMatsaev's (correct) suggestion to use:

```
os.system("../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/ZAP.exe")
```

The following would work as well:

```
os.chdir('../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/')
os.system("./ZAP.exe")
```

And, while it would be a bit pathologic (i.e. I can't imagine you'd want to do it) for this case, you could even modify the search path inside the code and then call the binary without a fully-qualified path:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/'
os.system("ZAP.exe")
```

Side-note:  AFAIK, there's no reason to attempt to store the `os.chdir` into the `current` variable, as [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a fully-qualified path:

```
os.system("../../../Programmi/OWASP/Zed Attack Proxy/ZAP.exe")
```

Comment: Answers are rarely posed in the form of a question.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sometimes that's just a cultural thing.  The answer could certainly use some more exposition/explanation, but the suggestion is, I'm fairly confident, correct.  Without having tested it (yet, but I will) myself, I'm assuming that `os.system` (just like most binary executions) doesn't execute files in the current directory unless they are on the search path.  Calling it with the path is probably necessary.

Comment: @nonDucor That's not really part of the question - The question is tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], which is a Windows feature that runs Linux distributions in a virtualized (WSL2) and/or syscall translation (WSL1) layer.  All versions of WSL provide an Interop feature to allow Windows PE binaries to run the a `binfmt_misc` registration from within the Linux layer.